# Finding any values less than the first occurrence of a value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `dplyr` or DT to determine if, after the first occurrence of a value, any subsequent values are less than that given value.

So if I have a data frame as below,

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
             num=c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2))
df2$id <- as.factor(df2$id)
```

I want to find the id's that have an occurrence less than 2 after the first occurrence of 2. For example, this would pick up id 1, since there is a 2 in the second row, but for that id, there are subsequent rows less than 2).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure I have to use any() somehow but I am. It sure how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `?Position` to me, though I'm not sure what output you want exactly:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)
df2[, Position(I,num==2) < Position(I,num < 2,right=TRUE,nomatch=FALSE), by=id]
#   id    V1
#1:  1  TRUE
#2:  2 FALSE
#3:  3  TRUE

 df2[, Position(I,num==2) < Position(I,num < 2,right=TRUE,nomatch=FALSE), by=id][,id[V1]]
#[1] 1 3
#Levels: 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, had never heard of this function.

Comment: Where is ?Position located?

Comment: @user85727 - typing `?Position` into the R console will bring up the help for `Position()` (and a bunch of other useful functional programming functions).

Comment: why doesn't your solution work when                                                                      df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
+  num=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2))?    In this case, all IDs are TRUE when only id=2 should be TRUE....

Comment: @user85727 - I think I have a mistake - does `df2[, Position(I,num==2) < Position(I,num < 2,right=TRUE,nomatch=FALSE), by=id]` work for you?

Comment: Nope, still returns all TRUEs.

Comment: @user85727 - just checked again - it gives `TRUE` for `id=2`

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `data.table`. Btw in your example ids 1 and 3 should be chosen as id 3 starts with a 2 and the next value is 1.

```
#first chain removes all rows for each group up to and including the first 2
#second chain returns the unique ids if a number less than 2 occurs
setDT(df2)[, .SD[-(1:which(num == 2)[1]), ], by = 'id'][which(num < 2), .(id = unique(id))]
```

Output:

```
   id
1:  1
2:  3
```

df2

```
> df2
    id num
 1:  1   1
 2:  1   2
 3:  1   1
 4:  1   1
 5:  1   2
 6:  2   1
 7:  2   1
 8:  2   1
 9:  2   2
10:  3   2
11:  3   1
12:  3   1
13:  3   1
14:  3   2
15:  3   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R version using the split-apply method.

```
levels(df2$id)[sapply(split(df2$num, df2$id),
                      function(i) if(any(tail(i, -which.max(i==2)) < 2)) TRUE else FALSE)]
[1] "1" "3"
```

I used `levels` to make sure that the order would follow `split`. The decision function in `if` uses `any` on a comparison of a truncated version of the vector that is sliced using `tail` and `which.max`.