# Extension to previous inquiry using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Previously, I was shown a solution to the question of how to use data table to select the IDs that have a 2 in a row and a 1 in any subsequent row, grouped by ID:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
         num=c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2))
df2$id <- as.factor(df2$id)
```

The solution was

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)
df2[, Position(I,num==2) < Position(I,num < 2,right=TRUE,nomatch=FALSE), by=id]
```

I am wondering now if there's a way using data.table to select the actual ROWS (or indexes thereof) that contain the values of 2 that are followed by a 1, instead of the above solution which just returns the ID *if* such an ordering exists.

Thanks.

Comment: Link to previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012667/finding-any-values-less-than-the-first-occurrence-of-a-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by getting the row index (`.I`) and then subset based on it

```
df2[df2[, .I[Position(I,num==2) < Position(I,num < 2,right=TRUE,nomatch=FALSE)], by=id]$V1]
```

Based on the OP's statement, my initial thought was to get the rows for the 'id's where the condition based on `Position` is met.  So, in this case the whole rows are returned for those 'id's that have values in 'num' where 1 will follow 2.

---

But, if we want the index of '2' for each 'id' which is followed by '1', then we can use

```
setDT(df2)[, .I[num==2 & shift(num, type = "lead", fill=0)==1], id]$V1
#[1]  2 10
```

and if we want to check not only the subsequent values but any values that follow the first '2' value for a particular 'id'

```
setDT(df2)[,  {i1 <- which(num==2)[1];  if(any(num[pmin(i1+1, .N):.N]==1)) .I[i1] } , id]$V1
#[1]  2 10
```

Comment: This isn't exalty what I meant.  What I meant was, I want to return the indices of the values of 2 that are followed by a 1 within the group.  So in df2, I want to return indices 2 and 10.

Comment: @user85727  Your statement in the post is `I am wondering now if there's a way using data.table to select the actual ROWS`

Comment: Yes, to select the actual rows that satisfy the property of being a 2 before a 1, or equivalently, get their indices.

Comment: Why does this not work when I change it to  setDT(df2)[, .I[num==2 & shift(num, type = "lead", fill=0)<2], id]$V1

Comment: @user85727  It works for me `setDT(df2)[, .I[num==2 & shift(num, type = "lead", fill=0)<2], id]$V1#
[1]  2  5  9 10 15` and I use data.table_1.10.4

Comment: But it doesnt. I get what you get but it is no longer grouping by IDs...  it should still only return 2 and 10. All I did was change ==1 to <2

Comment: @user85727 It does..  Check for where it returns the TRUE value based on your condition `setDT(df2)[,  num ==2 & shift(num, type = "lead", fill=0) < 2, id]`  With `fill=0`, the last value is 0 for each 'id', which is less than 2 of course and will meet the condition 'num==2 & ` num <2`  You may need to change the `fill = Inf` or so

Comment: @user85727  The problem is with the `fill` which is less than 2 by using 0.  You can change it to Inf i.e. `setDT(df2)[, .I[num==2 & shift(num, type = "lead", fill=Inf)<2], id]$V1
#[1]  2 10`

Comment: I think the `Position(I, cond)` way should be removed or at least put second. It's seriously unidiomatic to treat `I` as if it's a predicate function.